# how can I toggle convert Fahrenheit to Celsius using weather data from an API in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting weather data from an API (openweathermap.org) I've stored all the data I get from the API in a useState called "weatherData", and conditionally render the data in the jsx below. Now I'm trying to toggle convert the the temperatures I'm getting from the API from Fahrenheit to Celsius and back, so far I've created a function that tries to do this That starts the conversion process every time the uesr clicks a button. I got the weather data to convert properly from Fahrenheit to Celsius, but I have no clue how to display the new value into the jsx below. How can I do this?

```
function WeatherApp(){
//my useStates
    const [searchBar, setSearchBar] = useState('');
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState();
    const [currentTempUnit, setCurrentTempUnit] = useState('Farenheit');
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('C');

//function that get the search bar value when the user type something in
    function getSearchBarValue(e){
        setSearchBar(e.target.value.trim());
    }

//  a function that I am currently working that toggle convert the temperature units from Farenheit to Celcius and back.
//  I've got it to console log the correct value, but I have no clue how display the changed value on the page.
//  where you see "<span>{Math.round(weatherData.main.temp)}</span>" the conditionaly rendered jsx below. 
    function convertTemperature(){
        let tempUnit;
        
        if(currentTempUnit === 'Farenheit'){
            setCurrentTempUnit('Celcius');
            tempUnit = ( Math.round(weatherData.main.temp) - 32)/1.8;
            //setWeatherData(tempUnit)
            setButtonText('F');
        }else{
            setCurrentTempUnit('Farenheit');
            setButtonText('C');
        }

        console.log(tempUnit)
    }

//an async function that calls for weather data from an API. get the data then store that data in the weatherData useState to be used later. 
    async function getWeatherFromAPI(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const apiKey = 'fd7019c29121761f9602268492840876';
        try{
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchBar}&&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`, {mode: 'cors'})
            const storeWeatherData = await response.json();
            setWeatherData(storeWeatherData);
            console.log(storeWeatherData);
            
        }catch(err){
            err=alert("Im sorry we couldn't get you weather data")
        }
    }
    return(
        <>
            <div className="search-container">
                <form>
                    {/* The search bar  */}
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Enter City Here" className="search-bar"  onChange={getSearchBarValue}/>
                    {/* submit button that gets the data from the API */}
                    <button type="submit" className="search-btn"><FcSearch onClick={getWeatherFromAPI}/></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="weather-container">
                {/*  conditional rendering the useState weatherdata when asked for and found  */}
                {weatherData && 
                <div className="weather-content-container">

                    <section className="seaction-1">
                        <span>{weatherData.name}</span>
                        <span>{weatherData.sys.country}</span>
                        <img src={`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/${weatherData.weather[0]["icon"]}.svg`} />
                        {/* this is where I want to change values from F to C and back */}
                        <span>{Math.round(weatherData.main.temp)}</span>
                        <span>{Math.round(weatherData.main.temp_max)}</span>
                        <span>{Math.round(weatherData.main.temp_min)}</span>
                        {/* this is the button that triggers the temperature conversions */}
                        <button onClick={convertTemperature}>{buttonText}</button>
                    </section>

                    <section className="seaction-2">
                        <span>{weatherData.weather[0].description}</span>
                        <span>{weatherData.weather[0].main}</span>   
                    </section>

                    <section className="seaction-3">
                    <img src={humidityImgae} alt="humidity Icon"/>
                    <span>{weatherData.main.humidity}</span>
                    </section>
                </div>
                }

            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use burn Data, becuase I dont have the API in this moment

> Fahrenheit to Celsius Function

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [currentTempUnit, setCurrentTempUnit] = useState("Farenheit");
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("F");
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(20); // initial Temp F

  const toggleFToC = useCallback(() => {
    let tempUnit;
    if (currentTempUnit === "Farenheit") {
      setCurrentTempUnit("Celcius");
      tempUnit = ((weatherData - 32) * 5) / 9;
      setWeatherData(tempUnit);
      setButtonText("C");
    } else {
      setCurrentTempUnit("Farenheit");
      setButtonText("F");
    }
    console.log(tempUnit);
  }, [weatherData]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {buttonText} {weatherData}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleFToC()}>Toggle F to C</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```